# pfquery pass pfobject to another VC

Tags: ios, parse-platform, segue

I want to pass PFObject from VC1 to VC2. I know thats easy if I pass PFObject from Tableview to VC. Anyway, I have A VC with Tableview with the segue to detailVC (1) with ImageView. This ImageView would be shown in detailiamgeviewcontroller after tap image.(2) And I want to send pfobject to this Controller. But have no idea how to.
Any idea?

(1)

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetaill"])
{    
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.objecteditem = object;
}
```

(2)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.imageviewsecond setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objecteditem objectForKey:@"VlajkaURL"]]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [imageviewsecond addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sendi" sender:self];

    NSLog(@"image tapped!!!");

}
```

Comment: What's not working? Did you check at `viewDidLoad` the value of `objecteditem`?

Comment: First pass to Detailviewcontroller works great. This code is working. I just want to ask, how to pass PfObject from that detailviewcontroller to detailimageviewcontroller.

Comment: Do the same, but for going to `detailviewcontroller` to `detailimageviewcontroller`, what's in `prepareForSegue` for `sendi` `segue`?

Comment: prepareForSegue for sendi send user from detailviewcontroller to detailimageviewcontroller, where`s zoomable imageview, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same as you are already doing. In view 1 you are sending the object to view 2 (`DetailViewController2`). In `DetailViewController2`, in the `prepareForSegue` method, you do the same:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sendi"])
{    
        DetailImageViewController *detailImageViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailImageViewController.somePropertyName = self.objecteditem;
}
```

Comment: ye but when I tried to write into -(void) handleSingleTap method [self prepareForSegue:nil sender:self]; , it does nothing after tap image. Could give me some hint